# Bash file - if then-

Tags: linux, bash

I want to wright a login script for my organization,
The script needs to discover users by Group id's and then define the map drive they need on their computer.

I started writing down the script and it looks like this:

```
ID
if [gid=10524657]
then
    mkdir /home/likewise-open/Domain/Username/Desktop/Share
    sudo mount.cifs //fs01/salesnew /home/likewise-open/Domain/Username/Desktop/share -o user=X
else [gid=41654564] (etc....)
```

That is the first time i am writing a script in Ubuntu,

Can you tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Is it possible for Linux to identify the gid from the ID command ?
if not what is the alternative option?

Can someone please advise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, where to begin...

First, *nix systems are almost always case sensitive, so it is `id` and not `ID`.

Second, `id -g` will give you the GID.

Third you will probably want to capture the value of `id -g` in a variable:

```
GID=$(id -g)
```

Then you need to follow the proper form of an `if` statement in bash:

```
if [ "$GID" == "10524657" ]
then
   # do something
elif [ "$GID" == "41654564" ]
then
   # do something else
else
   # do the other thing
fi
```

And after all that, you should consider the fact the `sudo` command might be interactive, so the script will halt, waiting for user interaction, but running from a script it might have not access to tty (read: input from user interaction).

So please start by having a [basic introduction to bash scripting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWWvZa-qlRE)

Comment: Thanks for the information, I tried the following without a success - )
if [ "$GID" == "1052770817" ]
then
   mkdir /home/likewise-open/x/x/Desktop/test4
elif [ "$GID" == "41654564" ]
then
    mkdir /home/likewise-open/x/x/Desktop/test5
else
   mkdir /home/likewise-open/x/x/Desktop/test6
fi - the only directory that worked was the last(test6), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user2949827, Try to put an `echo $GID` statement in your code and check if the value you expect is the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that the `[` and `]` are in fact reserved words, therefore, you'll need whitespace around them (or semicolons or anything else that separates words).

You can get your effective gid like this

```
GID=`id -g`
```

then you can do

```
if [ "$GID" == "10524657" ]; then
    # some stuff
elif [ "$GID" == "41654564" ]; then
    # other stuff
else
    # else stuff
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, I tried the following without a success - ) if [ "$GID" == "1052770817" ] then mkdir /home/likewise-open/x/x/Desktop/test4 elif [ "$GID" == "41654564" ] then mkdir /home/likewise-open/x/x/Desktop/test5 else mkdir /home/likewise-open/x/x/Desktop/test6 fi - the only directory that worked was the last(test6), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user2949827 try to `mkdir /home/likewise-open/x/x/Desktop/x-${GID}-x` and look what folder appears :)